# The automorphism of a group when given a group presentation

Tags: group-presentation, automorphism-group, combinatorial-group-theory

How do you find the automorphism group when given a group presentation?

*See the comments for an attempt to answer by the user asking this question.*

Comment: At the level of generality at which you posed the question, you probably can't. Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: I do have a particular thing in mind, but it still is quite general:

$<x_{1},x_{2} , \ldots , x_{n} | x_{i} = w_{i} x_{p(i)} w_{i}^{-1} , i = 1 , 2 , \ldots , n > $ where $p(1) , p(2) , \ldots , p(n) $ are a permutation of $1 , 2 , \ldots , n $ and $w_{i} (i = 1 , 2 , \ldots , n)$ are words in $x_{1} , x_{2} , \ldots , x_{n}$ which satisfy the identity $\prod_{i = 1}^{n} x_{i}  = \prod_{i = 1}^{n } w_{i} x_{p(i)} w_{i}^{-1}$ in the free group $<x_{1} , x_{2} , \ldots , x_{n} >$

Comment: Given that the automorphism group is trivial iff the group is, the general problem is not decidable.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ...or $C_2$...

Comment: @user1729 Thank you. Not sure how I forgot that. I think it still makes it undecidable.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Undoubtably, as the isomorphism problem between $C_2$ and the trivial group is decidable...

Comment: @Jesse: I think the answer is "hard work". I have done two examples, and have found very different automorphism groups. One has $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong C_2$, the other has $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$...Do more examples. Try to find a pattern. Note that if $|w_i|=1$ then your group is a right-angled Artin group, and people study their (outer) automorphisms

Comment: Would the outer automorphism group be equally difficult to find?

Comment: @Jesse: The two examples I worked out were both abelian, so $\operatorname{Aut}(G)=\operatorname{Out}(G)$...(they were $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, incase you are wondering...)

Answer (score 0):

In order to close the question, here is @TobiasKildetoft's comment answering it:

> Given that the automorphism group is trivial iff the group is, the general problem is not decidable. – Tobias Kildetoft Apr 30 '13 at 13:51

*NB: This is community wiki.*